# STM32 I2C transmitting no data and cannot change the data that is being transmitted

Tags: stm32, i2c, arm, smbus

I am trying to establish a SMBus connection by using STM32 chip. When I try to transmit data to battery (0x0D) I see 0x0B with oscilloscope. When I change the data that is being transmitted to 0x00 or to 0xFF nothing changes. The data I see in oscilloscope is 0x0B. The slave address is 0x16. Interestingly I can communicate with battery. But it is unreliable. The related part of the code section is:

```
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c2; 
//! variable which holds the state of charge of Battery 1
int socBattery1;
//! variable which holds the state of charge of Battery 2
int socBattery2;
#define BATTERY_SMBUS_SLAVE_ADDRESS (0x16)

#define SMBBUS_GET_RELATIVE_SOC_COMMAND (0xFF)

int getBatterySOC(I2C_HandleTypeDef *batteryI2CHardwareHandle){
    memset (smbusData,0x00,16);
    smbusData[0] = SMBBUS_GET_RELATIVE_SOC_COMMAND;
    if (HAL_OK != HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(batteryI2CHardwareHandle,(uint8_t)BATTERY_SMBUS_SLAVE_ADDRESS,smbusData,2,1000)){
        memset (statusString,0x00,255);
        statusStringLength = sprintf(statusString,"I2C Transmit FAIL \r\n");
        CDC_Transmit_FS(statusString,statusStringLength);
        return -1;

    }

    if (HAL_OK != HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(batteryI2CHardwareHandle,(uint8_t)BATTERY_SMBUS_SLAVE_ADDRESS + 1 , smbusData,1,1000)){
        memset (statusString,0x00,255);
        statusStringLength = sprintf(statusString,"I2C Read FAIL \r\n");
        CDC_Transmit_FS(statusString,statusStringLength);
        return -1;

    }

    return smbusData[0];}

void StartDefaultTask(void const * argument)
{
  /* init code for USB_DEVICE */
  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 5 */
  int dischargeSOCLevel;
    socBattery1 = -1;
    socBattery2 = -1;

    currentDischargerState=DS_INITIALIZING;
    osDelay(13000);

    /* Infinite loop */
    for(;;)
    {if (socBattery1 == -1 && socBattery2 == -1){
            currentDischargerState = DS_FAULT;
        }
        else{

            if (socBattery1 < dischargeSOCLevel && socBattery2 < dischargeSOCLevel){
                currentDischargerState = DS_DISCHARGE_COMPLETE;
                user_pwm_setvalue( 0, &htim4, TIM_CHANNEL_3);
            }
            else{
                currentDischargerState = DS_DISCHARGING;
                pwm_value = 4500;
                user_pwm_setvalue( (12.0/ batteryVoltage1)*8000, &htim4, TIM_CHANNEL_3);
                if(socBattery1 > dischargeSOCLevel && socBattery2 > dischargeSOCLevel){
                    user_pwm_setvalue(6000,&htim2,TIM_CHANNEL_1);
                    user_pwm_setvalue(6000,&htim3,TIM_CHANNEL_1);
                }
                else if(socBattery1 > dischargeSOCLevel && socBattery2 < dischargeSOCLevel){
                    user_pwm_setvalue(6000,&htim2,TIM_CHANNEL_1);
                    user_pwm_setvalue(9999,&htim3,TIM_CHANNEL_1);
                                }
                else {
                                    user_pwm_setvalue(9999,&htim2,TIM_CHANNEL_1);
                                    user_pwm_setvalue(6000,&htim3,TIM_CHANNEL_1);
                                                }

            }
        }
osDelay(400);

    }

void StartSMBUSTask(void const * argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN StartSMBUSTask */
    /* Infinite loop */
    for(;;)
    {
        int receivedSOC;
        HAL_I2C_DeInit(&hi2c1);
                HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1);
        receivedSOC = getBatterySOC(&hi2c1);
        if (receivedSOC != -1){
            socBattery2 = receivedSOC;
        }
        osDelay(100);
        HAL_I2C_DeInit(&hi2c2);
                HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c2);
        receivedSOC = getBatterySOC(&hi2c2);
        if (receivedSOC != -1){
            socBattery1 = receivedSOC;
        }

        osDelay(100);
    }
  /* USER CODE END StartSMBUSTask */
}
```

I use 10 K pullups and the I2C frequency is 15 KHz. 
This is the oscilloscope view:(Yellow is clock and blue is data line)
So I cannot understand what might be the reason behind the unchanging data (0x0B) and I cannot see slave address that is being send in oscilloscope either. The only data that is being transmitted is 0x0B.

[image: Oscilloscope img]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not 0x0B. Data on oscilloscope is to address 0x16 and as the slave chip does not acknowledge there is no further data transmission.

Comment: How comes it is 0x16 tho? isn't it 0b 0010110 ?

Comment: 0x16 is 0001 0110. I don't understand what is unclear. I2C ack bit is the 9th bit so what is on scope screen is 0001 0110 1.  Or are you asking about why some datasheets use 7-bit addresses plus read/write bit so the 7-bit address is 0x0b for reading and writing and some datasheets use 8-bit addresses where write address is 0x16 and read address is 0x17?

Comment: Yes my bad I thought 0x16 as decimal. Thanks for the help